# How can I convert HTML file To Word Document in C# without using any API and doc.spire

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ms-word, vsto

I have created word file using this code.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        strHTMLContent.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head></head><body>");
        strHTMLContent.Append(var);
        strHTMLContent.Append("</body></html>");
        File.WriteAllText(@"E:\doc2.html", strHTMLContent.ToString());
```

> Now I converted this file to word using the following code

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

> But the problem is it directly show download option.
>   But I want to store it in Server

How to do it without using any API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work for every type of web page, but if you'd like to store only the text part(which I've just tested), you could do this:

1. Create a copy of that HTML file. (Optional step if the original HTML is necessary)
2. Change the extension of the copy to `.doc` which automatically converts it into a document file.

Comment: You can try to include images, tables etc. I'm 80% sure it'd work.

Comment: in word file is it support apply format in html like bold,italic etc??

Comment: Yes it is supporting both of them as it should, plus <br>, heading tags.
You can try out more tags yourself to see which ones are being supported.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: it's not supporting the page break style(<br clear=all style=\"mso-special-character:line-break;page-break-after:always\">). can you suggest an alternate way? @AkashAgarwal

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which convert html file to word file...

private string generateWordDoc()
        {

```
        object filename1 = @"E:\doc3.html";//path of html file
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object readOnly = false;
        object oFalse = false;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        oWord.Visible = false;

        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(ref filename1, ref oMissing, ref readOnly, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);


        filename1 = @"E:\new.doc"; // new document path
        object fileFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument;
        oDoc.SaveAs(ref filename1, ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        oDoc.Close(ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        oWord.Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);


        return "Success";

    }
```